# How can add a range of ip addresses in windows server machine in host file?

Tags: windows, authentication, server, ip, hosts

How can add a range of  ip addresses in windows server machine in host file?
This is for ip based access . How can add a range of ip addresses in this file?
file : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not uses hosts to do this, but your DNS. Most DNS will provide what's called a "Round Robin" if you assign multiple A records to the one name in the zone.

What it would do then, is the first request comes through would receive 192.168.244.128, the next would receive 192.168.226.129, so on and so forth. However, by design, your local machine will cache its DNS resolution, and will usually use the same IP address over and over, until it expires (Time To Live, TTL).

Source:
https://serverfault.com/questions/69836/point-multiple-ip-addresses-to-a-single-host-name